# Problems with mdx on next

Tags: reactjs, next.js13, mdxjs

I want to render mdx on next application. Syntax like heading, paragraph are working but table, code, blockquote etc are not working. Should I install any extra package or change any config? I followed the steps in next documentation for mdx support.

Dependencies in package.json:

```
    "@mdx-js/loader": "^2.3.0",
    "@mdx-js/react": "^2.3.0",
    "@next/mdx": "^13.4.19",
```

hello.mdx:

```
| a | b  |  c |  d  |
| - | :- | -: | :-: |

> Blockquote
```

I have a hello.mdx file in the app folder and importing like this :

```
import HelloWorld from "../../app/hello.mdx";
```

Answer (score 1):

MDX [doesn’t support GFM by default](https://mdxjs.com/guides/gfm/). To support GFM in MDX in Next.js, add the following to you `next.config.mjs`:

```js
import nextMDX from '@next/mdx'
import remarkGfm from 'remark-gfm'

const withMDX = nextMDX({
  options: {
    // More MDX options
    remarkPlugins: [remarkGfm],
  }
})

export default withMDX({
  // Next.js options
})
```

Also from [*What is MDX?*](https://mdxjs.com/docs/what-is-mdx/):

> Indented code does not work in MDX

Instead, use a fenced code block:

````markdown
```js
console.log('This is a code block')
```
````

Blockquotes should just work.